# Description of app in Google Play Games Services

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm currently integrating an app (a game) with Google Play Games Services. I'm wondering why it is necessary to have a separate title and description for the app there as well as the main app listing form?

Where is this data displayed?

Comment: Unsure, but it is probably used in the Google Play Games app

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is necessary to have this information.

The data is displayed in another application from google called "Google Play Games". You can download "Google Play Games" from the regular Google Play Store.